# Ansible - Avoid duplicates between group and host vars

Tags: ansible

I'm new at using ansible for server management and I need some help managing users and group's membership definition according to host and hosts-group, with a minimum of duplication and a maximum of scalability.

(25 users/20 groups over 50 hosts, with different "sudo" and "groups membership" at the end).

**The idea is to have:**

- "groups_vars" files defining the users (list or hash) to create on each host of the host group.
- "host_vars" files defining users for a specific host. (At the end, I will need nested groups, more than specific host_vars files)

I need these `\*_vars` files contents to be merged and not to be replaced (I understand how "vars precedence" work) because I want to avoid user declaration duplication.

To achieve this, I used hash syntax in `\*_vars` files and set `hash_behaviour=merge` in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

**Here are my files:**

My inventory:

```
all:
  children:
    type_a:
      hosts:
        vm1:
        vm2:
```

My debugging playbook :

```
- hosts: type_a
  tasks:
    - name: Debugging
      debug:
        msg: "{{ users }}"
```

group_vars/type_a.yaml :

```
users:
  user1:
    name: user1
  user2:
    name: user2
```

host_vars/vm1.yaml

```
users:
  user3_vm1_specific:
    name: user3_vm1_specific
```

At the end, I need the 3 users on the "vm1" and only "user1" and "user2" on "vm2" and then I will use the vars for the user creation.

Using the merge option (that will be deprecated in newer version of ansible) is working, but doesn't seem to be a best practice.

I searched here on StackOverflow and on other web sites, and most of the time the solutions are:

- to duplicate the user definition
  (more than 8 properties for each user and too many hostsgroup: unacceptable.)
- to use an other name for the second user list, then to assemble both using `{{ user_list1 + user_list2 }}`.

Not very scalable if we want to add many nested groups. You will need to add custom named list each time. It also, makes duplicates if "host_vars" and "group_vars" have the same user defined: it does not merge the content, but declares it twice with a different content each time.

My first solution is working, but using a near-deprecated option.
So what are the best practices in managing vars in this kind of situation ? (already have read the ansible documentation about vars but it didn't really helped me).

Also, maybe ansible tower or foreman could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple, easily maintainable, and flexible solution is to put users into one dictionary. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/users.yml 
users:
  groups:
    type_a:
      - user1
      - user2
    type_b:
      - user3
      - user4
  hosts:
    vm1:
      - user3_vm1_specific
    vm2:
      - user4_vm2_specific
```

Then the task below extracts all group's lists, add the host's list, makes the items unique, and sort it

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: type_a
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_users: "{{ (group_names|
                       map('extract', users.groups)|list +
                       users.hosts[inventory_hostname]|default([]))|
                       flatten|unique|sort }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_users
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [type_a] ****

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [vm1] => 
  my_users:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3_vm1_specific
ok: [vm2] => 
  my_users:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user4_vm2_specific
```

---

Notes:

- Lists are simpler in this use-case. Dictionaries are also possible, but the code would be more complex.
- A host can be a member of more groups.
- Single dictionary is easily maintainable, potentially created from an external DB (e.g. [Forman Manage Users](https://theforeman.github.io/foreman-ansible-modules/develop/plugins/user_module.html#theforeman-foreman-user-manage-users)).
- The task selecting the list is simple and under the admin's control.

Comment: If the vm2 dont have a user defined, it crashes but I suppose I can make jinja2 conditions for this.

Comment: Have you ever use foreman or tower, maybe can they manage inventory better than with this kind of var for my problem ?

Comment: 1) I've updated the task with "|default([])". "vm*" doesn't have to be defined in "users.hosts". 2) Ansible Tower is UI to Ansible with advanced management of playbooks, users, results, ... It doesn't provide different management of the variables. See [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#ansible-runner). 3) The same is valid for Forman. See [Forman Ansible Modules](https://theforeman.github.io/foreman-ansible-modules/develop/index.html).